# GCP Owner and Administrator roles for organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am assigned "Owner" role on the whole GCP organization, yet I cannot access organization IAM or billing accounts.
I've tried running a query on principal, I can see my account as a member of "roles/owner" role, but still nothing. Is it a bug or is it really intended do be so that owner role has less permissions than resourcemanager.organizationAdministrator? Thanks!

Comment: The IAM role `Owner` is a legacy role. This role does not have all roles/permissions. You can, however, add additional roles to your identity.

Comment: The problem is, I can't even read organization IAM permissions with my current role bindings, so it should be someone with superadmin or org admin roles to add those roles to my account... A bit strange

Comment: Since you mention billing accounts, I can assume that you are not the actual account owner, and you just have the role owner attached to a project granted by someone else? Edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

The basic difference between owner role and admin role is that:

An owner of an Organization is the member that has purchased the subscription. An owner has all privileges which include buying, upgrading, downgrading and cancelling subscriptions, modifying product access privileges, inviting and removing members from an Organization, and changing member roles. Each Organization can only have one owner.

Whereas, an admin of an Organization is a member that has privileges which include modifying product access privileges for other members, inviting and removing members from an Organization and changing member roles. An Organization can have more than one admin.

To confirm which role you have, you can run the below command:
gcloud iam roles describe ROLE_ID [--organization=ORGANIZATION     | --project=PROJECT_ID] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]

You can  refer [1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/describe) for any clarification on the above parameters or if you find any error.

To check what exact role you want for your billing account, you can refer the below link.
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#billing-roles

By default, the resource manager admin have project only authority, refer the below link.
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resource-manager-roles

Answer (score 1):

I gone through this troubleshooting and finally able to add the standard support offerings by giving myself all these permissions.

1. cloud support admin permission

---

gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding organizational_id --member='user:user_name@org.com' --role=roles/cloudsupport.admin

2. organization admin permission

---

gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding organizational_id --member='user:user_name@org.com' --role=roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin

3. Billing admin

---

gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding organizational_id --member='user:user_name@org.com' --role=roles/billing.admin

4. Tech support editor needed to create/view support cases

---

gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding organizational_id --member='user:user_name@org.com' --role=roles/cloudsupport.techSupportEditor

In addition to that you may need super admin permission.

Note: roles/owner is just the owner of the organization with access to all resources, this role does not give access to add standard support or view all IAM policies/roles

### To find the organization ID

gcloud organizations list